# Bicubic Interpolation example needed

Tags: c++

Can someone guide me along with the bicubic interpolation math as described on wikipedia with a numerical example?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation

I need to understand the math to create the algorithm for image resize.

What i don't understand from the wikipedia article is that how do i yield any of the 16 coefficients aij as mentioned in the article, how did they find the A^-1 matrix at the end? What's the point of forming the matrix?

I do understand bilinear interpolation by the way.

Can someone please illustrate the math with a numerical example or a link to one with numerical example? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the point of forming the matrix?

The point is to allow you to compute the 16 coefficients *a<sub>ij</sub>* from the 16 values (actual values and derivatives describing the curvature of the surface you want to interpolate).

What you know is the vector *x* as defined in the article (you compute the derivates by "looking around" the four points of the square). You then get the unknown vector *alpha* by computing *A<sup>-1</sup>x*. Knowing *alpha* you can now compute the bicubic interpolation function *p(x, y)* for any point inside the square.

> how did they find the A^-1 matrix at the end?

They inverted *A* that was defined by the 16 equations of 16 unknown values. Inverting a matrix is pretty straightforward linear algebra.

Comment: You mentioned they inverted A that was defined by the 16 equations of 16 unknown values. Can you be more specific as to how the matrix of A is filled up with the values such as 0,1,-3,-6,-9 etc in the first place? Where did they get these values from? I'm not very good at math, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @f0rfun: It is basic linear algebra how to solve N linear equations with N unknowns using a matrix. The easiest way to explain it probably doing it "visually" by stacking the equations vertically, however that is hard to do in a comment. You could read a textbox on the subject or try to google it. I quickly found this link: http://home.ubalt.edu/ntsbarsh/Business-stat/otherapplets/SysEq.htm